# get channel that message forwarded from that

Tags: python-3.6, telegram, telethon

i use latest telethon framework. this implement a wrapper on telegram API.
i want get info (title ,about, participant_count) and some recent messages from channels that a message forwarded from that to me.
how can do this?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code and tested it with version ‍‍`1.0.4` :

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, sync
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetHistoryRequest

api_id = XXXXXX
api_hash = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
phone_number = '+9893XXXXXX'
################################################
channel_username = 'test_ali3'
################################################

client = TelegramClient('session_name',
                    api_id,
                    api_hash, 
                    )
client.connect()
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone_number)
    me = client.sign_in(phone_number, input('Enter code: '))


channel_entity = client.get_entity(channel_username)

posts = client(GetHistoryRequest(
    peer=channel_entity,
    limit=1,
    offset_date=None,
    offset_id=0,
    max_id=0,
    min_id=0,
    add_offset=0,
    hash=0))

for post in posts.messages:
    print(post)
```

You can see the list of all the channels that messages forwarded from in the ‍**Chat** section. (you can get `title`,`username`, `channel_id`,`photo`)
[image]

[image]

If you want more information(like `about`,`participants_count`), you can use `GetFullChannelRequest` in your code :

for example :

```
more_info1=client(GetFullChannelRequest(posts.chats[1]))
```

[image]